# Apache POI supports only ScatterCharts and LineCharts why?

Tags: java, excel, charts, apache-poi

I see that only `LineChart` and `Scatter Charts` are supported by default with `Apache POI`.

**Question:**
How can we add Other Chart types in spreadhsheet..

Any Idea or any help on this? or Is there Any reason for apache supporting only these two types of charts.

Comment: Because it's an Open Source, Volunteer driven project, and those are the only chart types which people have volunteered their time + effort to contribute?

Comment: Ok. So I guess Other Chart types can also be implemented but not yet done by anyone.

Answer (score 6):

Apache poi provides `poi-ooxml-schemas` also. This are the underlying objects for `XML` based office documents. So one can try solving his requirements directly with those objects as long as they are not provided at higher level. The problem is the documentation of those objects. As far as I know there is none. But there is http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/.

So coming from the `XSSFChart` from the existing chart examples we can get `CTChart` and then using http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/org/openxmlformats/schemas/drawingml/x2006/chart/CTChart.java#CTChart shimmy up from object to object.

It is helpful to create a simple `*.xlsx` file first directly with `Excel` and have a look at its `XML` content. There we can get hints what objects are needed. For this we can unzip the `*.xlsx` simply with a `ZIP` software.

In this example create a workbook with one sheet and the simplest possible pie chart in `Excel`. Unzip the `*.xlsx` and look at `/xl/charts/chart1.xml`.

Example Pie Chart:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.charts.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFChart;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTChart;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTPlotArea;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTPieChart;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTBoolean;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTPieSer;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTAxDataSource;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTNumDataSource;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTNumRef;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTStrRef;


public class PieChart {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
        Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Sheet1");

        Row row;
        Cell cell;
        for (int r = 0; r < 3; r++) {
            row = sheet.createRow(r);
            cell = row.createCell(0);
            cell.setCellValue("S" + r);
            cell = row.createCell(1);
            cell.setCellValue(r+1);
        }

        Drawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
        ClientAnchor anchor = drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 20);

        Chart chart = drawing.createChart(anchor);

        CTChart ctChart = ((XSSFChart)chart).getCTChart();
        CTPlotArea ctPlotArea = ctChart.getPlotArea();
        CTPieChart ctPieChart = ctPlotArea.addNewPieChart();
        CTBoolean ctBoolean = ctPieChart.addNewVaryColors();
        ctBoolean.setVal(true);
        CTPieSer ctPieSer = ctPieChart.addNewSer();

        ctPieSer.addNewIdx().setVal(0);     

        CTAxDataSource cttAxDataSource = ctPieSer.addNewCat();
        CTStrRef ctStrRef = cttAxDataSource.addNewStrRef();
        ctStrRef.setF("Sheet1!$A$1:$A$3"); 
        CTNumDataSource ctNumDataSource = ctPieSer.addNewVal();
        CTNumRef ctNumRef = ctNumDataSource.addNewNumRef();
        ctNumRef.setF("Sheet1!$B$1:$B$3"); 

System.out.println(ctChart);

        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("workbook.xlsx");
        wb.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.close();
    }
}
```

Disclaimer: tested with Excel 2007, works not with Libreoffice and Openoffice.

This example needs the full jar of all of the schemas `ooxml-schemas-1.3.jar` as mentioned in the [FAQ-N10025](https://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10025).

---

To make this working using `apache poi 4.1.0` following needs to be changed:

```
...
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*;
//import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.charts.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFChart;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFDrawing;
...
        XSSFDrawing drawing = (XSSFDrawing)sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
        ClientAnchor anchor = drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 20);

        XSSFChart chart = drawing.createChart(anchor);
...
```

And it then needs the full jar of all of the schemas `ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar`.

Comment: Thanks for this!

I just tried it and Excel 2013 gives an error when opening it and removes the chart... do you have any idea as to what can be happening? Thanks!

Comment: @LuTHieR: This was very minimalistic. Only the elements which were minimal needed. Now the CTPieSer needs a Idx. Have updated it.

Comment: Would it be too much to get a similar example for other chart types, like a Bar Chart? I'm trying to build one using your example and various pieces of code found around the web like http://www.massapi.com/source/github/76/39/763962266/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/charts/XSSFLineChartData.java.html#115, but I can't seem to make it work, and Excel just says its wrong, doesn't give me any pointers as to what's the problem :( Thanks again!!

Comment: @LuTHieR: The principle is as described here: Create a workbook with one sheet and the simplest possible bar chart in Excel. Unzip the *.xlsx and look at /xl/charts/chart1.xml to get the needed XML. Then, coming from the XSSFChart from the existing chart examples, get CTChart and then, using grepcode, shimmy up from object to object. You could post your current not working code here as a new question about apache poi bar charts. Then I can have a look at it and maybe help.

Comment: Great, thank you! I will try doing that and if I can't get it to work I'll post the new question.

Comment: I tried... but could not make it work. I even tried adding empty legends and axis, and even pasting the axis from the example chart I created to use as a reference into the generated chart1.xml, but to no avail. Could you please take a look at it when you have some time? Many thanks!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38913412/create-bar-chart-in-excel-with-apache-poi

Answer (score 0):

following [Create Bar Chart in Excel with Apache POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38913412/create-bar-chart-in-excel-with-apache-poi) more closely I get this which gives a raw result for pie charts which displays in librecalc

```
public static void pieChart(SXSSFSheet sheet) {
    Row row;
    Cell cell;
    for (int r = 0; r < 3; r++) {
       row = sheet.createRow(r);
       cell = row.createCell(0);
       cell.setCellValue("S" + r);
       cell = row.createCell(1);
       cell.setCellValue(r+1);
   }

   Drawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
   ClientAnchor anchor = drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 20);

   Chart chart = drawing.createChart(anchor);

   CTChart ctChart = ((XSSFChart)chart).getCTChart();
   CTPlotArea ctPlotArea = ctChart.getPlotArea();
   CTPieChart ctPieChart = ctPlotArea.addNewPieChart();
   CTBoolean ctBoolean = ctPieChart.addNewVaryColors();   
   ctBoolean.setVal(true);


   for (int r = 1; r < 4; r++) {
       CTPieSer ctPieSer = ctPieChart.addNewSer();
       CTSerTx ctSerTx = ctPieSer.addNewTx();
       CTStrRef ctStrRef = ctSerTx.addNewStrRef();
       ctStrRef.setF("Sheet1!$A$" + r);
       ctPieSer.addNewIdx().setVal(r-2);
       CTAxDataSource cttAxDataSource = ctPieSer.addNewCat();
       ctStrRef = cttAxDataSource.addNewStrRef();
       ctStrRef.setF("Sheet1!$A$1:$A$3");
       CTNumDataSource ctNumDataSource = ctPieSer.addNewVal();
       CTNumRef ctNumRef = ctNumDataSource.addNewNumRef();
       ctNumRef.setF("Sheet1!$B$1:$B$3");

    //at least the border lines in Libreoffice Calc ;-)

 ctPieSer.addNewSpPr().addNewLn().addNewSolidFill().addNewSrgbClr().setVal(new byte[] {0,0,0});
    }
}
```

ubuntu 16.04 / POI 3.17 / jdk 8

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Apache POI 4.0.0, the LineChart and ScatterChart from XSSF have been moved to a new XDDF component where BarChart and PieChart from XSLF have been moved too. Based on the new framework for charts, the RadarChart has been implemented. These five chart types are now available from XSSF (xslx spreadsheets), XSLF (pptx slides) and XWPF (docx documents).

It seems to be now easier to implement the missing chart types like AreaChart, BubbleChart or SurfaceChart. The 3D variants might require some additional dedication to get implemented. Finally the new chart types like SunBurstChart or TreeMapChart require implementation of a whole brand new part called "chartex".