# Use values outside excel cell in apache poi Bar chart

Tags: excel, charts, apache-poi, bar-chart

I am trying to create a bar chart in excel file using Apache poi and following the code mentioned here: 
[Create Bar Chart in Excel with Apache POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38913412/create-bar-chart-in-excel-with-apache-poi).

In my case, I need to use data values coming from a different source instead of the excel cells. How can I use those values in the BarChart?

Assume that the values will come as an array of float/double values. Also, I need to be able to set Bar colors independently. For example, some bars will be green while some others will be red.

I modified the data portion of [Create Bar Chart in Excel with Apache POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38913412/create-bar-chart-in-excel-with-apache-poi) code in the following manner:

```
 CTBarSer ctBarSer = ctBarChart.addNewSer();
 CTSerTx ctSerTx = ctBarSer.addNewTx();
 CTStrRef ctStrRef = ctSerTx.addNewStrRef();
ctStrRef.setF("hardcoded" + r);
ctBarSer.addNewIdx().setVal(r-2);
CTAxDataSource cttAxDataSource = ctBarSer.addNewCat();
CTStrData ctStrData = cttAxDataSource.addNewStrLit();
ctStrData.addNewPt().setV("Val1");
ctStrData.addNewPt().setV("Val2");
ctStrData.addNewPt().setV("Val3");

CTNumDataSource ctNumDataSource = ctBarSer.addNewVal();

CTNumData ctNumData = ctNumDataSource.addNewNumLit();
CTNumVal ctNumVal = ctNumData.addNewPt();
ctNumVal.setV(String.valueOf(0.92));

ctNumData = ctNumDataSource.addNewNumLit();
ctNumVal = ctNumData.addNewPt();
ctNumVal.setV(String.valueOf(0.95));

ctNumData = ctNumDataSource.addNewNumLit();
ctNumVal = ctNumData.addNewPt();
ctNumVal.setV(String.valueOf(0.98));
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

When I output the excel file using print, it gives the following result:

```
<xml-fragment xmlns:char="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/chart" xmlns:main="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main">
  <char:plotArea>
    <char:layout/>
    <char:barChart>
      <char:barDir val="col"/>
      <char:varyColors val="false"/>
      <char:ser>
        <char:idx val="0"/>
        <char:tx>
          <char:strRef>
            <char:f>hardcoded2</char:f>
          </char:strRef>
        </char:tx>
        <char:spPr>
          <main:ln>
            <main:solidFill>
              <main:srgbClr val="000000"/>
            </main:solidFill>
          </main:ln>
        </char:spPr>
        <char:cat>
          <char:strLit>
            <char:pt>
              <char:v>Val1</char:v>
            </char:pt>
            <char:pt>
              <char:v>Val2</char:v>
            </char:pt>
            <char:pt>
              <char:v>Val3</char:v>
            </char:pt>
          </char:strLit>
        </char:cat>
        <char:val>
          <char:numLit>
            <char:pt>
              <char:v>0.92</char:v>
            </char:pt>
          </char:numLit>
          <char:numLit>
            <char:pt>
              <char:v>0.95</char:v>
            </char:pt>
          </char:numLit>
          <char:numLit>
            <char:pt>
              <char:v>0.98</char:v>
            </char:pt>
          </char:numLit>
        </char:val>
      </char:ser>
      <char:axId val="123456"/>
      <char:axId val="123457"/>
    </char:barChart>
    <char:catAx>
      <char:axId val="123456"/>
      <char:scaling>
        <char:orientation val="minMax"/>
      </char:scaling>
      <char:delete val="false"/>
      <char:axPos val="b"/>
      <char:tickLblPos val="nextTo"/>
      <char:crossAx val="123457"/>
    </char:catAx>
    <char:valAx>
      <char:axId val="123457"/>
      <char:scaling>
        <char:orientation val="minMax"/>
      </char:scaling>
      <char:delete val="false"/>
      <char:axPos val="l"/>
      <char:tickLblPos val="nextTo"/>
      <char:crossAx val="123456"/>
    </char:valAx>
  </char:plotArea>
  <char:plotVisOnly val="true"/>
</xml-fragment>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Main problems with your changings are:

1. You forgot setting the `Idx` of the `CTStrVal` and the `CTNumVal`, you have added using `addNewPt`.
2. `CTNumData` added to `CTNumDataSource` with `addNewNumLit` should contain as much `CTNumVal`s like there are data points in the series. There should not be multiple `CTNumData`in one series. With `CTStrData` in `CTAxDataSource` you have done it right - except the missing `Idx`, see 1.

Following  code is creating the same chart as the one in the linked answer but without cell references:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.charts.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFChart;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTChart;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTPlotArea;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTBarChart;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTBoolean;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTBarSer;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTAxDataSource;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTNumDataSource;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTSerTx;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTCatAx;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTValAx;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTScaling;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTLegend;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.STAxPos;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.STBarDir;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.STOrientation;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.STLegendPos;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.STTickLblPos;

/*
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTNumRef;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTStrRef;
*/

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTStrData;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTNumData;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTNumVal;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTStrVal;

public class BarChartPlainValues {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
        Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Sheet1");

/*
cell filing code deleted
*/

        Drawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
        ClientAnchor anchor = drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 8, 20);

        Chart chart = drawing.createChart(anchor);

        CTChart ctChart = ((XSSFChart)chart).getCTChart();
        CTPlotArea ctPlotArea = ctChart.getPlotArea();
        CTBarChart ctBarChart = ctPlotArea.addNewBarChart();
        CTBoolean ctBoolean = ctBarChart.addNewVaryColors();
        ctBoolean.setVal(true);
        ctBarChart.addNewBarDir().setVal(STBarDir.COL);

//new code start

        for (int s = 1; s < 5; s++) {
           CTBarSer ctBarSer = ctBarChart.addNewSer();
           CTSerTx ctSerTx = ctBarSer.addNewTx();
           ctSerTx.setV("Serie " + s);
           ctBarSer.addNewIdx().setVal(s-1);  

           CTAxDataSource ctAxDataSource = ctBarSer.addNewCat();
           CTStrData ctStrData = ctAxDataSource.addNewStrLit();
           ctStrData.addNewPtCount().setVal(3);
           CTStrVal ctStrVal = ctStrData.addNewPt();
           ctStrVal.setIdx(0);
           ctStrVal.setV("HEADER 1");
           ctStrVal = ctStrData.addNewPt();
           ctStrVal.setIdx(1);
           ctStrVal.setV("HEADER 2");
           ctStrVal = ctStrData.addNewPt();
           ctStrVal.setIdx(2);
           ctStrVal.setV("HEADER 3");

           CTNumDataSource ctNumDataSource = ctBarSer.addNewVal();
           CTNumData ctNumData = ctNumDataSource.addNewNumLit();
           ctNumData.addNewPtCount().setVal(3);
           CTNumVal ctNumVal = ctNumData.addNewPt();
           ctNumVal.setIdx(0);
           ctNumVal.setV("" + new java.util.Random().nextDouble());
           ctNumVal = ctNumData.addNewPt();
           ctNumVal.setIdx(1);
           ctNumVal.setV("" + new java.util.Random().nextDouble());
           ctNumVal = ctNumData.addNewPt();
           ctNumVal.setIdx(2);
           ctNumVal.setV("" + new java.util.Random().nextDouble());

           //at least the border lines in Libreoffice Calc ;-)
           ctBarSer.addNewSpPr().addNewLn().addNewSolidFill().addNewSrgbClr().setVal(new byte[] {0,0,0});   

        } 

//new code end

/*
chart reference code deleted
*/

        //telling the BarChart that it has axes and giving them Ids
        ctBarChart.addNewAxId().setVal(123456);
        ctBarChart.addNewAxId().setVal(123457);

        //cat axis
        CTCatAx ctCatAx = ctPlotArea.addNewCatAx(); 
        ctCatAx.addNewAxId().setVal(123456); //id of the cat axis
        CTScaling ctScaling = ctCatAx.addNewScaling();
        ctScaling.addNewOrientation().setVal(STOrientation.MIN_MAX);
        ctCatAx.addNewDelete().setVal(false);
        ctCatAx.addNewAxPos().setVal(STAxPos.B);
        ctCatAx.addNewCrossAx().setVal(123457); //id of the val axis
        ctCatAx.addNewTickLblPos().setVal(STTickLblPos.NEXT_TO);

        //val axis
        CTValAx ctValAx = ctPlotArea.addNewValAx(); 
        ctValAx.addNewAxId().setVal(123457); //id of the val axis
        ctScaling = ctValAx.addNewScaling();
        ctScaling.addNewOrientation().setVal(STOrientation.MIN_MAX);
        ctValAx.addNewDelete().setVal(false);
        ctValAx.addNewAxPos().setVal(STAxPos.L);
        ctValAx.addNewCrossAx().setVal(123456); //id of the cat axis
        ctValAx.addNewTickLblPos().setVal(STTickLblPos.NEXT_TO);

        //legend
        CTLegend ctLegend = ctChart.addNewLegend();
        ctLegend.addNewLegendPos().setVal(STLegendPos.B);
        ctLegend.addNewOverlay().setVal(false);

System.out.println(ctChart);

        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("BarChartPlainValues.xlsx");
        wb.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.close();
    }
}
```

Problem: Normally arrays of string literals like `={"HEADER 1","HEADER 2","HEADER 3"}` are not allowed as axis labels. Only references are allowed here. `Excel` accepts this while rendering the chart but you cannot edit those axis labels in `Excel` GUI.