# Apache Poi bar Chart Errors

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm new in Apache-poi, I'm working on a java project using Apache-poi to export data to excel spreadsheet, now I am stuck on exporting Bar Chart. Firstly I am getting the following exception: **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTBarChart** i have included all the necessarily jar files but still giving me errors

Another problem I have is that I can't trace the row and column where a bar graph is taking  a value from. I know how to set it but I don't know where you specify in the bar graph code where to take the value. I used the code in the following link below: [Create Bar Chart in Excel with Apache POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38913412/create-bar-chart-in-excel-with-apache-poi)

Comment: which jars did you include? where did you include them?

Comment: i included jars in this folder : poi-bin-3.16-20170419 and ooxml-schemas-1.3

Comment: are they included in the classpath or where?

Comment: i included em in the classpath

Comment: The `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` occurs on run time. So it seems the `ooxml-schemas-1.3.jar` is in the classpath while compile time but not while run time. That's why I do using some `IDE`s very reluctantly. They do not helping much but are much time consuming because of such problems. A `IDE` is helping resolving problems which I would not have without the `IDE` ;-).