# Apache POI generate excel chart

Tags: java, excel, charts, apache-poi

All:

Pretty new to Apache POI and excel VBA, how can I implement something like this in Java with Apache POI or any other java lib:

VBA code in Excel:

```vb
Sheets("Sheet 1").ChartObjects("Line Chart")
.Chart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = Sheets("Sheet 1").Range("A37")
```

I can not find any Chart related API working like this, any thought?

Another way around is: My goal is to use Java automatically update cell A37 and give its value as "Line Chart"'s xAxis Max scale, is there a way now to directly call this VBA code thru POI?

Thanks,

Comment: Apache POI had limited support for charts last time I used it (which was a few years ago. See here for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/38920290/1356423. As the POI docs note though..."You can however create a chart in Excel using Named ranges, modify the chart data values using HSSF and write a new spreadsheet out. This is possible because POI attempts to keep existing records intact as far as possible." https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/limitations.html

Comment: @AlanHay Thanks, but sorry that I am still very new to POI, could you give one example? I can see the line chart has been already there in that Sheet, I know how to update cell A37, but I just have no idea how can pass that value to that Chart object in Java

Answer (score 1):

Answer for current latest stable version `apache poi 3.17`. Note [XSSFChart](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFChart.html) is in development. So we should using [XDDFChart](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xddf/usermodel/chart/XDDFChart.html) for later versions.

You can get a `List` of [XSSFChart](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFChart.html)s from the sheet's drawing via [XSSFDrawing.getCharts](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFDrawing.html#getCharts--). From that `List` get your needed `XSSFChart`. Then get that chart's axes via [XSSFChart.getAxis](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFChart.html#getAxis--). Then get the appropriate [XSSFValueAxis](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/charts/XSSFValueAxis.html) from that `List`. And then change it's maximum via [XSSFChartAxis.setMaximum](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/charts/XSSFChartAxis.html#setMaximum-double-).

Example:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.charts.*;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

class ReadAndWriteExcelXSSFChart {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("WBWithLineChart.xlsm"));
  Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

  Row row = sheet.getRow(36); if (row == null) row = sheet.createRow(36);
  Cell cell = row.getCell(0); if (cell == null) cell = row.createCell(0);

  cell.setCellValue(10);

  double valueA37 = cell.getNumericCellValue();

  Drawing drawing = sheet.getDrawingPatriarch();
  if (drawing instanceof XSSFDrawing) {
   for (XSSFChart chart : ((XSSFDrawing)drawing).getCharts()) {
System.out.println(chart.getPackagePart().getPartName().getName());
    if (chart.getPackagePart().getPartName().getName().endsWith("chart1.xml")) { //first chart in sheet
     for (XSSFChartAxis axis : chart.getAxis()) { //all axes
System.out.println(axis);
      if (axis instanceof XSSFValueAxis) { //value axis
       axis.setMaximum(valueA37); // maximum = same value as in A37
System.out.println(axis.getMaximum());
      }
     }
    }
   }
  }

  workbook.write(new FileOutputStream("WBWithLineChart.xlsm"));
  workbook.close();

 }
}
```