# Apache poi - Bar Chart Set min and max values for left axis

Tags: java, charts, apache-poi, bar-chart

Hi I'm using apache poi 3.17 and I made a bar chart using the `org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTChart` interface, like the image below:

I need to set the min and max value for the left axis.
Something like  0 and 1 to adjust the columns.

Using `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.charts.ValueAxis` I can do that with the methods: `setMinimum(0)` and `setMaximum(1)` .

Is that possible ? using the package `org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart`.
If yes which class or iterface should I use?

[image]

Anyone can help me?

The code I use to set CTValAx is below and I get in this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38913412/create-bar-chart-in-excel-with-apache-poi)

```
          CTValAx ctValAx = ctPlotArea.addNewValAx(); 
          ctValAx.addNewAxId().setVal(123457); 
          ctScaling = ctValAx.addNewScaling();
          ctScaling.addNewOrientation().setVal(STOrientation.MIN_MAX);
          ctValAx.addNewDelete().setVal(false);
          ctValAx.addNewAxPos().setVal(STAxPos.L);
          ctValAx.addNewCrossAx().setVal(123456); 
          ctValAx.addNewTickLblPos().setVal(STTickLblPos.NEXT_TO);
```

Comment: Please show at least the code where you are setting the `CTValAx`.

Comment: @AxelRichter
This part of code I get from another question. I believe that was you that answered. Sorry I'm a beginner developer and my 
knowledge about java and poi is so small

Comment: Yes but at the time I had answered, the linked documentation of `grepcode.com` was available as information resource. Now it is down and so we need doing `javadoc` our own to get information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there is not a API documentation of `org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart` public available. So we need downloading the sources of `ooxml-schemas` from http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/poi/ooxml-schemas/1.4/ for example and doing `javadoc` with those.

Then we will find `org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTValAx` providing `addNewScaling()` which returns a `CTScaling` which provides  `addNewMax()` and `addNewMin()` which are returning `CTDouble` and provide `setVal(double val)`.

```
    CTScaling ctScaling = ...
    ...
    CTValAx ctValAx = ctPlotArea.addNewValAx(); 
    ctValAx.addNewAxId().setVal(123457); //id of the val axis
    ctScaling = ctValAx.addNewScaling();
    ctScaling.addNewOrientation().setVal(STOrientation.MIN_MAX);

    ctScaling.addNewMin().setVal(0.2);
    ctScaling.addNewMax().setVal(0.7);

    ctValAx.addNewDelete().setVal(false);
    ctValAx.addNewAxPos().setVal(STAxPos.L);
    ctValAx.addNewCrossAx().setVal(123456); //id of the cat axis
    ctValAx.addNewCrosses().setVal(STCrosses.AUTO_ZERO); //this val axis crosses the cat axis at zero
    ctValAx.addNewTickLblPos().setVal(STTickLblPos.NEXT_TO);
    ...
```