# Apache POI "cannot access CTSkip"

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm encountering an issue trying to use Apache POI 5.2.3.  I'm attempting to set the category axis mark interval and label.

As mentioned in another question(https://stackoverflow.com/a/66670362/2212458). The following code is supposed to handle this:

```
    chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getCatAxArray(0).addNewTickLblSkip().setVal(2); // label only every second mark
    chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getCatAxArray(0).addNewTickMarkSkip().setVal(2); // show only every second mark
```

However, this results in a build error "error: cannot access CTSkip" and "class file for org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTSkip not found".

Other portions of the namespace are accessible such as CTTitle, CTNumFormat, CTTickMark are accessible, but for some reason CTSkip is not.  How do I work around this issue?

Comment: What `poi-ooxml` jars are you using?

Comment: @Gagravarr Library is coming from MavenCentral via gradle "implementation group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml', version: '5.2.3'".  This should result in poi-ooxml-5.2.3.jar getting used.

Comment: Try swapping from `poi-ooxml-lite` to `poi-ooxml-full` ?

Comment: @Gagravarr It does appear to be in poi-ooxml-full.  Probably for convenience poi-ooxml pulled in poi-ooxml-lite automatically.  In order to use poi-ooxml-full I had to explicitly exclude the poi-ooxml-lite transient dependency.  Thanks.

Comment: implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-full:5.2.3'
    implementation ('org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:5.2.3') {
        exclude module: 'poi-ooxml-lite'
    }